# CSS Hamburger doesn't spin when expanding sidenav

Tags: html, css

I can't get my ccs made hamburger to open expand/collapse my sidenav, to top it off. If i get it to expand/collapse, then it stops spinning. Please see  [**codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BREKpB) **demo**, thanks for the feedback

I think i made a mistake in the css, but i'm having a hard time tracing the issue. I would really appreciate a second pair of eyes.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row d-flex d-md-block flex-nowrap wrapper">
    <div class="col-md-2 float-left col-1 pl-0 pr-0 collapse width show" id="sidebar">
      <div class="list-group border-0 card bg-faded text-center text-md-left">
        <a class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar" href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> <span class="hidden-sm-down">Item 4</span></a>
        <a class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar" href="#"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> <span class="hidden-sm-down">Item 5</span></a>
        <a class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar" href="#"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <span class="hidden-sm-down">Link</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <main class="col-md-10 float-left col px-5 px-md-3 py-3 main">
      <!--<a data-target="#sidebar" data-toggle="collapse" href="#">
            a
            </a>-->
      <div class="outer-menu">
        <input data-target="#sidebar" class="checkbox-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" type="checkbox">
        <div class="hamburger">
          <div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <h1 class="display-3 hidden-xs-down">Bootstrap 4 Dashboard</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#sidebar {
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 3;
}
#sidebar .list-group {
    min-width: 300px;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

#sidebar .list-group-item {
    border-radius: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
    #sidebar {
        min-width: 35px;
        max-width: 40px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: visible;
        transition: all 0.25s ease;
        transform: translateX(-45px);
        position: fixed;
    }

    #sidebar.show {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

    #sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar{ width: 0px; }

    #sidebar, #sidebar .list-group {
        min-width: 35px;
        overflow: visible;
    }
    /* overlay sub levels on small screens */
    #sidebar .list-group .collapse.show, #sidebar .list-group .collapsing {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 190px;
        top: 0;
    }
    #sidebar .list-group > .list-group-item {
        text-align: center;
        padding: .75rem .5rem;
    }
    /* hide caret icons of top level when collapsed */
    #sidebar .list-group > .list-group-item[aria-expanded="true"]::after,
    #sidebar .list-group > .list-group-item[aria-expanded="false"]::after {
        display:none;
    }
}

.collapse.show {
  visibility: visible;
}
.collapsing {
  visibility: visible;
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition-property: height, visibility;
  transition-property: height, visibility;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.collapsing.width {
  -webkit-transition-property: width, visibility;
  transition-property: width, visibility;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}


/* hamburger */

/*********************/
.outer-menu {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  opacity: 0;
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle:checked + .hamburger > div {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle:checked + .hamburger > div:before,
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle:checked + .hamburger > div:after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle:checked + .hamburger > div:after {
  opacity: 0;
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle:checked ~ .menu {
  pointer-events: auto;
  visibility: visible;
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle:checked ~ .menu > div {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-duration: .75s;
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle:checked ~ .menu > div > div {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0.4s;
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle:hover + .hamburger {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle:checked:hover + .hamburger > div {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}
.outer-menu .hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  background: rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.75);
  border-radius: 0 0.12em 0.12em 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: box-shadow 0.4s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.outer-menu .hamburger > div {
  position: relative;
  flex: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fefefe;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.outer-menu .hamburger > div:before,
.outer-menu .hamburger > div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: inherit;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.outer-menu .hamburger > div:after {
  top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: provide jsfiddle link

Comment: @GauravPaliwal doesn't work, it won't properly display the content. There is a see codepen demo liinked above.

Comment: @DanielH the icon doesn't rotate but it does move the nav :( THank you tho. Someone gave an answer below that resolved the issue. I'm trying to understand why his changes fixed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your codepen doesn't work, jquery should be loaded first.

Anyway, here's my attempt to fix it. View it in full screen mode.
Once jquery is properly loaded, your code works except for the spinning effect because your selector is wrong.

See **hamburger** & **X button** section in CSS.

```css
#sidebar {
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 3;
}
#sidebar .list-group {
    min-width: 300px;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

#sidebar .list-group-item {
    border-radius: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
    #sidebar {
        min-width: 35px;
        max-width: 40px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: visible;
        transition: all 0.25s ease;
        transform: translateX(-45px);
        position: fixed;
    }
    
    #sidebar.show {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

    #sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar{ width: 0px; }
    
    #sidebar, #sidebar .list-group {
        min-width: 35px;
        overflow: visible;
    }
    /* overlay sub levels on small screens */
    #sidebar .list-group .collapse.show, #sidebar .list-group .collapsing {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 190px;
        top: 0;
    }
    #sidebar .list-group > .list-group-item {
        text-align: center;
        padding: .75rem .5rem;
    }
    /* hide caret icons of top level when collapsed */
    #sidebar .list-group > .list-group-item[aria-expanded="true"]::after,
    #sidebar .list-group > .list-group-item[aria-expanded="false"]::after {
        display:none;
    }
}

.collapse.show {
  visibility: visible;
}
.collapsing {
  visibility: visible;
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition-property: height, visibility;
  transition-property: height, visibility;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.collapsing.width {
  -webkit-transition-property: width, visibility;
  transition-property: width, visibility;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}


/* hamburger */

/*********************/
.outer-menu {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  opacity: 0;
}
.outer-menu .hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  background: rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.75);
  border-radius: 0 0.12em 0.12em 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: box-shadow 0.4s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.outer-menu .hamburger > div {
  position: relative;
  flex: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fefefe;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle.collapsed ~ .hamburger > div {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
} 

.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle + .hamburger > div:before,
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle + .hamburger > div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: inherit;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle.collapsed + .hamburger > div:before {
  top: -10px;
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle.collapsed + .hamburger > div:before,
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle.collapsed + .hamburger > div:after {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  opacity: 1;
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle.collapsed + .hamburger > div:after {
  top: 10px;
}
/* X button */

.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle + .hamburger > div {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle + .hamburger > div:before,
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle + .hamburger > div:after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle + .hamburger > div:after {
  opacity: 0;
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle ~ .menu {
  pointer-events: auto;
  visibility: visible;
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle ~ .menu > div {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition-duration: .75s;
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle ~ .menu > div > div {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease 0.4s;
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle:hover + .hamburger {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle.collapsed:hover + .hamburger > div {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.outer-menu .checkbox-toggle:hover + .hamburger > div {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row d-flex d-md-block flex-nowrap wrapper">
    <div class="col-md-2 float-left col-1 pl-0 pr-0 collapse width collapse" id="sidebar">
      <div class="list-group border-0 card bg-faded text-center text-md-left">
        <a class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar" href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> <span class="hidden-sm-down">Item 4</span></a>
        <a class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar" href="#"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> <span class="hidden-sm-down">Item 5</span></a>
        <a class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar" href="#"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <span class="hidden-sm-down">Link</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <main class="col-md-10 float-left col px-5 px-md-3 py-3 main">
      <!--<a data-target="#sidebar" data-toggle="collapse" href="#">
            a
            </a>-->
      <div class="outer-menu">
        <input data-target="#sidebar" class="checkbox-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" type="checkbox">
        <div class="hamburger">
          <div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <h1 class="display-3 hidden-xs-down">Bootstrap 4 Dashboard</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: JSfiddle didn't display properly for my code or yours, i'll try your implementation right now.

Comment: i can genuinely say that i don't understand why that fixed it but i'll do my best to learn :) Thanks again. Now i need to turn that into a top nav. I appreciate you fixing it, i was stuck for hours on that.